# How to convert a mutable HashMap into an immutable equivalent in Scala?

Tags: scala, immutability, scala-collections, mutable

Inside a function of mine I construct a result set by filling a new mutable HashMap with data (if there is a better way - I'd appreciate comments). Then I'd like to return the result set as an immutable HashMap. How to derive an immutable from a mutable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
scala> val m = collection.mutable.HashMap(1->2,3->4)
m: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map(3 -> 4, 1 -> 2)

scala> collection.immutable.HashMap() ++ m
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4)
```

or

```
scala> collection.immutable.HashMap(m.toSeq:_*)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4)
```

Comment: But the result is an `immutable.Map`, not an `immutable.HashMap` then! The function is meant to return `immutable.HashMap`.

Comment: You can specify whatever type you want.  If you want the type to be `Map`, do `Map() ++ m`

Comment: I want `immutable.HashMap`, but `immutable.HashMap ++ m` (where `m` is a `mutable.HashMap`) returns `immutable.Map`.

Comment: The result is `immutable.HashMap` if you say `immutable.HashMap(m.toSeq:_*)`, as shown in the answer.

Comment: By the way, what's your reason for needing the type to be `HashMap`?  It's generally best to only assume the "interface" type, like `Map` to allow your program to be flexible for different `Map` implementations.

Comment: Yes, it's better to consume as generic types as possible, but to provide as specific types as possible, isn't it?

Comment: @Ivan Not really. If you provide a `HashMap`, then you'll never be able to change into something else. Say, for example, you later need a `LinkedHashMap`, but someone is already depending on you returning a `HashMap`. Inside a module, that's ok. On anything public, keep to interfaces.

Comment: @daniel-c-sobral, but aren't there any side effects of turning a `HashMap` into a `Map`? Doesn't `HashMap` provide any functionality a bare `Map` doesn't? It is still not clear for me whether or not I have reasons to return a `HashMap`, I am afraid a reason can actually exists so I can regret switching to a `Map` in future.

Answer (score 13):

Discussion about returning `immutable.Map` vs. `immutable.HashMap` notwithstanding, what about simply using the `toMap` method:

```
scala> val m = collection.mutable.HashMap(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4)
m: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map(3 -> 4, 1 -> 2)

scala> m.toMap
res22: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(3 -> 4, 1 -> 2)
```

As of 2.9, this uses the method `toMap` in `TraversableOnce`, which is implemented as follows:

```
def toMap[T, U](implicit ev: A <:< (T, U)): immutable.Map[T, U] = {
    val b = immutable.Map.newBuilder[T, U]
    for (x <- self)
        b += x

    b.result
}
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing 'Map.newBuilder'. I've normally used mutable maps just for the construction of immutable ones.

Comment: Is there any tangible difference? I always wondered whether `newBuilder` keeps only one copy of the data in memory or does it perform a full copy of rhe data on `.result`, thus requiring double the memory amount?

Comment: You can check the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/MapBuilder.scala): `MapBuilder.result` just returns `elems`, so it doesn't create a new copy. From this my understanding is that this is exactly the same as doing a `+` operation on the *immutable* collection, and no *mutable* collection is involved.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a map : `logMap: Map[String, String]`
just need to do : `logMap.toMap()`